# Installing zerorpc on openshift without sudo access + installing yum install libpq-dev dependancy

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am having a problem running npm install zerorpc without sudo access.

a dependency install attempt yum install libpq-dev
does

```
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

for the npm install attempt I get the error 
-- any ideas on how to install zerorpc with out sudo access?

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zerorpc
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zerorpc
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/openshift/53475f0f50044611030002fb/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/openshift/53475f0f50044611030002fb/node_modules']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/lib/openshift/53475f0f50044611030002fb/node_modules',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/var/lib/openshift/53475f0f50044611030002fb/node_modules/zerorpc',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23',
npm ERR!      '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.bz844450.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm" "install" "zerorpc"
npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/53475f0f50044611030002fb
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.17
npm ERR! path /var/lib/openshift/53475f0f50044611030002fb/node_modules
npm ERR! fstream_path /var/lib/openshift/53475f0f50044611030002fb/node_modules/zerorpc
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/openshift/53475f0f50044611030002fb/node_modules'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: 'npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.bz844450.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm" "install" "zerorpc"
npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/53475f0f50044611030002fb
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.17
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/openshift/53475f0f50044611030002fb/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't remember exactly what I was trying to do; long time ago :)